# Would reposting this vim question from SO be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

When searching for the same solution I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32973075/6342442) on SO. It didn't do so well there, but I'd like an answer to the same question.

Would it be acceptable to post the same question here on Vim.SE?

I think that, here, I might get an answer from someone with more detailed knowledge of regex and Vim's syntax highlighting system. I answered the question with my best regex fix, but my regex knowledge is not very deep.

Comment: Also see the "linked" sidebar for that question for some more related discussions. In brief, if you feel a better answer can be given then what's on Stack Overflow: then **yes**, feel free to re-post. If the question is already adequately answered: then **no**, probably best to not re-post.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. That's basically what I wanted to know.

Comment: An example of such a question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/310/205